# E tenho uma dúvida a respeito de select no banco sqlite no WP

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone

Comecei a utilizar o banco SQLite no Windows Phone.

E tenho uma dúvida a respeito de select no banco SQLite.

```
/*
List items = null;
items = App.db.Query(“select Nome from Usuario”);
ListBox.ItemsSource = items;
*/
```

Este select comentado funciona para mostrar os dados em listbox. Ou seja, dá para mim ver se está salvando os dados no BD. E está salvando!

MAS estou querendo fazer algo assim:

```
// ————
string Email;
Email = App.db.Query(“select Email from Usuario”).ToString();

MessageBox.Show(Email);
//————-
```

Tentei também assim (me passaram para tentar):

```
var returnedCollection = App.db.Query(“select Email from Usuario”);
for (int i = 0; i < returnedCollection.Count(); i++)
{
string email = (returnedCollection[i]).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(email);
}

return;
```

Mas também não funcionou só aparece BD.Usuario no MessageBox.

Answer (score 1):

O AP resolveu assim:

```
var returnedCollection = App.db.Query(“select Email from Usuario”);
for (int i = 0; i < returnedCollection.Count(); i++)
{
MessageBox.Show(returnedCollection[0].Email.ToString());
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/ListUsers.cs).